# should I build own NLP engine for rare language or use cloud services for chatbots (azure, GCP) and translations?

Tags: azure, google-cloud-platform, nlp, chatbot

So, I would like to build a `chatbot` for a language not widely supported (i.e. `goole`/`azure` don't have support for building chatbots, but only translation service). Translation works well from that language to English (and vice versa).

So, is it easier:

1. To build a new NLP engine for that specific language to recognize context of user question when using the chatbot?
2. To translate user questions to English and then internally use chatbot engine which supports English (of course, the chatbot needs to be
       programmed), i.e. azure/GCP engines. When context is recognized, and
       when used provide answer (it can again be translated to destination 
       language toward user) ?

Method 2 seems easier (cloud api/services already available). Not sure how it works in practice when recognizing context is this chained?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go for method 2 -->[multilingual conversations](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/17.multilingual-conversations) that helps to translate and identify the intent.